# не могу сделать похожий наплыв элементов

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно сделать такой же наплыв углов

вот что получается у меня

код

```css
body {
  background-color: #cacaca;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.square_smole1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.square_smole2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.square_smole1_1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.square_smole1_2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.square_smole2_1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.square_smole2_2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>КАМАСУТРА</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="square_smole1">
      <div class="square_smole1_1"></div>
      <div class="square_smole1_2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="square_smole2">
      <div class="square_smole2_1"></div>
      <div class="square_smole2_2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: вот что получается у меня]

Comment: Так вроде то что нужно... Или еще маленьких, зелененьких квадратиков добавить?

Comment: Да нужны как раз эти маленькие квадратики

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.block {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
}

.square_smole1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.square_smole1_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aqua;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.square_smole1_2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aqua;
  top: 180px;
  left: 180px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.square_green1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  top: 180px;
  left: 180px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.square_smole2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: aqua;
  top: 380px;
  left: 380px;
  z-index: 5;
}

.square_smole2_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 6;
}

.square_green2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 7;
}

.square_smole2_2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  top: 180px;
  left: 180px;
  z-index: 8;
}

.square_green3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  top: 180px;
  left: 180px;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DOC</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="square_smole1">
      <div class="square_smole1_1"></div>
      <div class="square_smole1_2"></div>
      <div class="square_green1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square_smole2">
      <div class="square_smole2_1"></div>
      <div class="square_green2"></div>
      <div class="square_smole2_2"></div>
      <div class="square_green3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Можно рассмотреть вот такой вариант "наклеивания" маленьких зеленых квадратов на стыки больших и средних

Comment: спасибо большое, я пробовал z-index но видимо не разобрался как он работает. Еще раз спасибо

Comment: Не за что) рада была помочь). В z-index ничего особо сложного нет. Главное понимать очередность, что на что Вы хотите наклеить)

Answer (score 0):

> нужны как раз эти маленькие квадратики

Предложу такой вариант...

Я там немного поменял твои стили и плюсом добавил еще отрисовку тех самых квадратиков...

```css
body {
  background-color: #cacaca;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.square_smole1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.square_smole2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
.square_smole2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}

.square_smole1_1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.square_smole1_2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
.square_smole1_2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
.square_smole2_1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.square_smole2_2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
.square_smole2_2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>КАМАСУТРА</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="square_smole1">
      <div class="square_smole1_1"></div>
      <div class="square_smole1_2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="square_smole2">
      <div class="square_smole2_1"></div>
      <div class="square_smole2_2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Там не квадратики а бленд мод который даёт прозрачность скорее всего